# UWP - What happens if navigating away from page while async/await is running?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

In a UWP app (or any C# app with a UI), what happens when an async method hasn't finished, but user navigates away from the page? My more specific concern is that when await is completed, the async method  will continue and modify certain UI elements, but the user has navigated away from the page already.

| User enters Page
| Clicks on button
| Enters async method
| Hits await (returns to process events)
| User navigates away from Page
| awaited method completes
| ?

At this point, does the async method continue? If it does continue, and it tries to modify a UI element, will the app crash because the Page no longer exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The async method will continue and your page will exist in memory. Your method can make modifications, but obviously they're unnecessary changes. Your app should not crash, unless you're trying to access elements that no longer exist. Such as `Panel.Children[2].Opacity = 0` where `Panel` is now empty after being unloaded from screen. (just an example)

If your method runs for a long time, you should cancel the operations using a `CancellationToken` or a flag of some sort to allow you to "early-out" of the routine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with **navigate away**. If this means that you close your form on a neat way and thus Dispose all your disposable items, then the form will still exist in memory, after all the context of your thread still holds references to objects in your form.

However, most `System.Windows.Forms.Control` objects throw exceptions when you access them after they have been Disposed.

Example:

```
private void OnButtonShowMyAsyncForm_Clicked(objece sender, Eventargs e)
{
    using (var form = new MyAsyncForm(...))
    {
        var dlgResult = form.ShowDialog(this);
        ProcessResult(dlgResult);
    }
    // here your form and all controls on it are disposed, but not collected yet
    // if an async thread does something with any of the controls
    // like enable a button, an exception is thrown.
}
```

So it would be neater to have a Form.Closing event handler check if any process is still running, and either cancel closing, or wait until the process is finished.

```
private void OnFormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    bool asyncProcessRunning = this.MyTask != null && !this.MyTaks.IsCompleted;
    if (processRunning)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Can't close. Task still running", this.Text, 
            MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
 }
```

An even neater way would be to notify the operator and give him the possibility to

- Retry: maybe task finished by now,
- Ignore: do not wait until task finished, but take precautions that no problems occur when task finishes
- Cancel: cancel the closing of the form

Comment: Just a thought: `System.Windows.Forms` was about three (!) generations earlier than the OP asked...